# How to check if a scheduled Powershell script has failed to run in Nagios

Tags: nagios

I have a requirement where I need to be notified when a scheduled Powershell script fails at any point of time. I would like to configure a Nagios service for this, and need someone to point me in the right direction.

Cheers.

Shadab

Answer (score 0):

There may be a power shell-specific way of doing this, but let me give you two ideas:

1) is there some output of the program that you can monitor?  A log file that gets touched when the script runs, etc?  If so, you can monitor that file in nagios.

or,

2) can you modify the script to send an "I finished" message to nagios?  If so, you can setup a notification when that message has not been received (goes "stale").

Comment: Hi Alian, The powershell script does open and close a connection with SQL Server and executes a few DML statements in between.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use exit codes. Check out documentation on Nagios Plugin API, but below are the exit/return codes you should use in your script:

```
Plugin Return Code  Service State   Host State
              0     OK              UP
              1     WARNING         UP or DOWN/UNREACHABLE
              2     CRITICAL        DOWN/UNREACHABLE
              3     UNKNOWN         DOWN/UNREACHABLE
```

Here's an example of a script I wrote for an Icinga check, maybe this will help give you some ideas?: (http://www.baremetalwaveform.com/?p=311 for full article)

```
$state = (rstcli64 --information --volume 2> Out-Null | select-string -Pattern "State:") -split "`r"

If (
($state.count -gt 0) -and ($state.count -eq ($state | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_ -match "Normal"}).count) 
)
{
#OK
Write-Host "RST Volume state OK"
exit 0
}

If (
$state.count -eq 0
)
{
#UNKNOWN
Write-Host "RST Volume state UNKNOWN"
exit 3
}

else
{
#CRITICAL
Write-Host "RST Volume state CRITICAL"
exit 2
}
```